# Setting the vertical size of a dashboard app

Tags: rally

Is there a way to set the vertical size of a custom dashboard app?  By default, cutsom apps can be expanded or contracted vertically.  This is not always needed or desired.

Additionally, the 2.0 custom grid and the resize capability sometimes does not work well (size does not stick properly etc.), especially with the paging information that is standard at the bottom of the 2.0 custom grid.

Comment: To the extent that AppSDK 1.0 apps have always played within a dedicated full page iFrame until the 2012.05.05 Rally release, it's unlikely they have any sizing methods that can affect their container "window".

AppSDK 2.0 could get this at some point - the developers would know more. The frame size and positioning methods are managed by the Rally/dashboard "container" in which they reside, but I'd be surprised if any hooks exist right now that might make those methods accessible to the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Moving answer response from comment...oops... to answer:

To the extent that AppSDK 1.0 apps have always played within a dedicated full page iFrame until the 2012.05.05 Rally release, it's unlikely they have any sizing methods that can affect their container "window". AppSDK 2.0 could get this at some point - the developers would know more. The frame size and positioning methods are managed by the Rally/dashboard "container" in which they reside, but I'd be surprised if any hooks exist right now that might make those methods accessible to the SDK